# Summation of numbers $ (n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+m)$ over $n$

Tags: summation

> Verify that if $V_n = n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+m)$ then  $$V_{n+1} - V_n = (m+1)(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+m)$$
>   Given now that $U_n  =  (n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+m)$ find sum of series $U_n$ from $N$ to $1$ in terms of $m$ and $N$.

I have done the first part of the questions. Having trouble with the sum part. Don't know how to approach it

Comment: The big hint is that you were asked to do something else just before you were asked to find the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
$$V_{n+1}-V_n=\color{red}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+m)}(n+1+m)-n\color{red}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+m)}$$
$$=(n+1+m-n)\color{red}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+m)}=(m+1)\color{red}{U_n},$$
we have
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{N}U_k&=\frac{1}{m+1}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(V_{k+1}-V_{k}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{m+1}\left\{(V_2-V_1)+(V_3-V_2)+\cdots+(V_N-V_{N-1})+(V_{N+1}-V_N)\right\}\\&=\frac{1}{m+1}\left(V_{N+1}-V_1\right)\\&=\frac{1}{m+1}\left\{(N+1)(N+2)\cdots (N+1+m)-1\cdot 2\cdots (m+1)\right\}.\end{align}$$

Comment: @user140161: I think your $V_{n+1}-V_{n}$ is wrong and in my answer I calculated the sum from $1$ to $N$.

Comment: You're right, it was a typo. I have edited it. I dont understand how $V_{n+1}$ - $V_n$ equals (m+1)($U_n$).

Comment: @user140161: Do you understand the first line of my answer?

Comment: I got it, I was carelessly missing something. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user140161: You are welcome. I'm glad to help you.